# How to instruct Google Home to play YouTube videos from *my* playlists

Tags: google-home, chromecast

Everytime I ask Google Home to play a YouTube video, it searches for (seemingly) random playlists that may contain that video... sometimes it doesn't.

I have my own playlists, with a specific video.

How do I instruct Google Home to play a video from **my** YouTube playlist?

*Edit: Requests I've tried:*

[This is the video I want to play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU). Please note on the web, simply typing "Frozen Let It Go" brings up this video 100% of the times (even in incognito)

- Play Frozen Let It Go on TV
- Play Frozen Let It Go on YouTube on TV
- Play Let It Go sing-along on TV
- Play Let It Go sing-along by Disney on TV
- Play Frozen Let It Go sing-along on TV

Most of the times it brings the [Demi Lovato cover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHue-HaXXzg)
Other times it loads playlists (again, either with Demi Lovato cover, or others)

I have a playlist called "Frozen Sing Along", but I am unable how figure out how to tell Google Home to search within **my** playlists.

I've tried "Play Frozen Sing Along on TV", but again, it picks up random playlists, not mine.

Comment: So, it has been 2.5 yrs since this question was asked and Google still has no fix for this hiccup on their part? I'm about to tear my hair off! Has anyone been able to find a workaround? Much obliged.

Comment: Make your playlist public, add a routine like instructed here, and set the Music command to "<YOUR_USERNAME> <YOUR_PLAYLIST_NAME>". This works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested this out extensively as I really want to be able to verbally initiate one of my Youtube playlist via Google Home.

The good news is that can, but only for your Liked videos. I use a Routine to initiate this (because it gives you flexibility that specify a preferred verbal command. Here's how I have set it up in Google Home app on my Android mobile

1. Open Home app and go to Account/Settings/Assistant/Routines
2. Select 'Add action' for the 'When I say' action and type "My Videos" (or whatever you prefer to say to initiate the routine)
3. Select 'Music' option for the 'My Assistant Should' action, and then select the right hand cog (settings) icon.
4. Enter the following text *[your Youtube user name] "Liked videos* where it ask 'What music would you like to play?. Just to clarify, here's the exact text I have entered which is between these quotes "Sydney_Robster Liked videos"
   5 Use back button to return to the previous page and select the tick at the top of the page to save this Routine.
5. Initiate your Youtube Liked Videos Routine my saying to Google Home/Assistant, "Hey Google, My Videos" (or whatever command you defined). The routine will play your Liked Videos in the order that they have been created in Youtube. If you want to randomise it, then additionally say "Hey Google, shuffle"

Another useful command for the Google Home/Assistant is when you are watching Youtube cast to chrome device, is if you see a new video you like, say "Hey Google, like". The Assistant will reply "I have noted that you like this" and the Assistant will 'like' the video and it will be appended to your list.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't a way to do this right now.  You might be able to get it to play your entire playlist by name, but not an individual song from your playlist.

Google Home does the same thing with Google Play Music -- you can't ask for a specific song you have uploaded or in one of your playlist.  You can ask for one of your whole playlists to play, or you can ask for a song but then it picks which version of that song for you instead of the one you have specifically in one of your playlists.

Hopefully Google will improve the Google Home functionality soon.

Comment: I know it's likely not an easy thing to find, but do you have a reference which shows that it's currently not possible?

Comment: How do I instruct it to play **my** playlist? It has a rather generic name "Frozen Sing Along". There are many other playlists by the same name. I want to prioritize the search to look for my playlists first. I really don't want to create a long cryptic unique playlist name... this is meant for my kids.